# python file not providing output in atom using angular

Tags: python, angularjs, atom-editor

learning how to use angular and python on atom text editor

this is my angular code in index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl">

      {{myData}}
    <!-- <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="x in myData">
        {{x.name}},{{x.age}}
      </li>
    </ul> -->

    </div>
  </body>
</html>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('test.py').then(function(response) {
        $scope.myData = response.data;
    });
});
</script>
```

and the python code is as below in test.py:

```
import json

message = "Hello World"
#test = [{'name':'sample1','age':'24'},{'name':'sample2','age':'25'}]
print json.dumps(message)
```

the commented code is what i really want to do, but i am not able to get the simple code work either.
when i run the code on live server, this is the output i see on the page http://127.0.0.1:3000/index.html:

```
import json message = "Hello World" #test = [{'name':'sample1','age':'24'},{'name':'sample2','age':'25'}] print json.dumps(message)
```

Comment: Are you following a tutorial for this? If so, could you link to it? The problem is with your `http.get` call. It's not sending a request to your Python script, it's just getting the contents of the script and displaying that.

Comment: Yes. it is getting the content of the script instead of the result, this is the link to the tutorial - https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_http.asp

Comment: That tutorial makes a request to an HTML file. Since browsers don't interpret Python, it doesn't seem like the right thing to do to simply drop your script in its place. Are you running this on a server?

Comment: yes, i am using atom's live server package

Comment: Do you know if `live-server` has the capability of interpreting Python?

Comment: i am not sure if i am being honest, i cant seem to find out online if it does either .. do you have any suggestions, holland ?

Comment: Maybe, but I need to know whether this for a bigger project, or if you are just teaching yourself.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158821/discussion-between-harsha-jasti-and-holland-wilson).